# Unknown javadoc format for JavaRDD error in Eclipse in Windows 10

Tags: windows, eclipse, apache-spark, javadoc

I can't get the Javadoc for Spark core library to work on Eclipse and Windows 10. I have no JRE defined under preferences. I load the Javadoc I right-clicked on the jar file in eclipse-> project explorer -> maven -> download Javadoc. What I typically do. See attached image. How to fix this?

Stack Trace is:

```
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Unknown javadoc format for JavaRDD {key=Lorg/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD<Ljava/lang/String;>;} [in JavaRDD.class [in org.apache.spark.api.java [in C:\Users\karln\.m2\repository\org\apache\spark\spark-core_2.11\2.2.1\spark-core_2.11-2.2.1.jar]]]]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavadocContents.getTypeDoc(JavadocContents.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getAttachedJavadoc(BinaryType.java:999)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.javadoc.JavadocContentAccess2.getHTMLContent(JavadocContentAccess2.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:757)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.internalGetHoverInfo(JavadocHover.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavadocHover.getHoverInfo2(JavadocHover.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.BestMatchHover.getHoverInfo2(BestMatchHover.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.hover.JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.getHoverInfo2(JavaEditorTextHoverProxy.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewerHoverManager$4.run(TextViewerHoverManager.java:166)
```

And Eclipse Version

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600
```

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

EDIT: Added Error Detail Screenshot.

[image: Error Detail Screenshot]

Comment: Please find the corresponding file from which the Javadoc comes (Javadoc HTML or source code) and extend your question with the corresponding Javadoc comment.

Comment: @Howlger Error detail screenshot added.

Comment: I mean, where does Eclipse (or here: Maven) get the Javadoc from? Can you see the source code of `JavaRDD`? Maybe the attached source code or Javadoc is already broken.

Comment: @howlger I assume it downloads it from repository.apache.org - either way the Javadoc get into my local repository. The source I just downloaded and it looks like scala source so the Spark project might be using something non standard for Javadoc creation. I submitted an eclipse bug report, we'll see what they say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Spark Project Core 2.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.2.1) **Javadoc JAR** [`spark-core_2.11-2.2.1-javadoc.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.2.1/spark-core_2.11-2.2.1-javadoc.jar) does not contain Javadoc, but only **HTML documentation that differs in content and structure from Javadoc**. Obviously, the HTML documentation was created from Scala source code (see [`spark-core_2.11-2.2.1-sources.jar`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.2.1/spark-core_2.11-2.2.1-sources.jar)).

Thanks for [reporting it to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=529688). In my view, this is not a bug of Eclipse, but caused by an **invalid Spark Core Javadoc JAR**. Unfortunately, the Eclipse error message is somewhat misleading.

You can **validate the attached Javadoc of a JAR** as follows:

1. Right-click `spark-core_2.11-2.2.1.jar` and choose *Properties*
2. In the *Properties* dialog go to *Javadoc Location*
3. Click *Validate...*

Comment: Right, if you extract the `spark-core_2.11-2.2.1-javadoc.jar` file and open `index.html` you get all scala classes. Looks like scala has finally wormed its way into my life!